# Click many buttons with same name from a website- Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to navigate through a page and start adding to cart all products from the list.
By doing that i want to click whatever it has the button "Agree".

Here is my code

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url.com");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Agree")).Click();                 
  }
```

Here is a screenshot with my buttons and their details in "Inspect"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're happy that you just click each of the found elements up to 10, then this will work.

```
var buttons = driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Buy")).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    buttons[i].Click();                 
}
```

Alternatively if you want to click each button once use a foreach

```
foreach(button in buttons)
{
   button.Click();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have updated my question because it seems that i cannot even press the button i want :/